# Stryker or Mystique?

Tags: marvel, x-men

I watched the latest X-men movie and I am a bit confused about the identity of the person.

Is it Stryker or is it Mystique we see when they fish logan up?

Mystiques blood was obtained in Paris. So there was "time" to expperiment with it and  inject Stryker.

I might be wrong but I can't remember Stryker getting killed in the movie.

Comment: In the movie it's never made explicitly clear who it is, but I think it's pretty much accepted that it's Mystique disguised as Striker. And Striker survives, he just gets knocked around and electrocuted by Mystique a little bit.

Comment: @Daft It is explicitly clear. You see a flash of Mystique's yellow eyes with a smirk before the scene ends.

Comment: @krillgar *Mystiques blood was obtained in Paris. So there was "time" to experiment with it and inject Stryker.* I think the OP is asking whether it's Mystique disguised as Stryker, or if Stryker now has Mystique's powers and is showing Wolverine this by flashing his eyes yellow.

Comment: @Daft In Paris, only a few drops of her blood were recovered, and that was at most a couple of weeks before the events of DC. Even today, that wouldn't be enough blood to experiment with. As I said, there wasn't enough time to experiment with in the 70s. I understood what the OP was questioning, and I'm commenting on why that premise (and yours) is wrong. Even if we were to accept that you are correct, Stryker could not have been showing off to Wolverine in that scene as his back was to Logan.

Comment: @krillgar don't they have 30ft robot sentinels outside the white house by the end of the movie? Sentinels with chips that could detect a mutant by it's DNA, and only by being in close proximity to the mutant, not even requiring any skin or hair or blood. Do you really think they could have made them in the 70s? Could they even do it today? I don't think they stayed through to the technology of the time very much at all.

Comment: 30ft robot sentinels with jet packs for chests and machine guns for arms... **SUPER REALISTIC!!**

Comment: @InguShama The machine gun arms and jet pack chest *maybe*, I don't really know the state of that sort of tech in the 70s. But the chip Trask put in them to detect mutants... probably not.

Comment: It's so obvious that I can't believed this is being asked

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The film's director, Simon Kinsberg has [explicitly confirmed](http://www.empireonline.com/features/days-of-future-past-secrets-explained/p6) that it's Mystique at the end, impersonating Stryer;

> ***Q. WHY IS MYSTIQUE PLAYING STRYKER AT THE END OF THE FILM?***
>
> **Kinsberg** : *“I wanted Wolverine to end up with Stryker at the end of the film, but
> when we got down the line on that, it felt like such a downer ending,
> and there wasn’t any ripple in time. It was the same – the location
> where Stryker grabbed Logan was different, but Logan’s fate was very
> much the same. I felt like we hadn’t made enough of a ripple.*
>
> *“So from there we thought about who else it could be. I was thinking
> of having other people on the boat – he could be fished out by Charles
> and Hank – but **we set this thing up where Mystique is masquerading as
> a military character saving mutants from going into some sort of
> experimental programme in Saigon early on**, so there’s a really nice
> symmetry there at the end.”*

And in [this interview](http://www.scifinow.co.uk/news/x-men-days-of-future-past-ending-explained-spoilers/) with ScifiNow

> It’s a neat little handwave, because there’s still loads of things we
> don’t know – like how Logan ended up in the Weapon-X project and got
> his Adamantium skeleton **if he was being led away by
> Mystique-as-Stryker and not Stryker himself.**

Answer (score 2):

It's Mystique posing as Stryker. Also Stryker survives the movie. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Stryker#Film

Comment: This isn't wrong, but link-only answers are of low quality since the link may die, leaving only assertion.